# Состояние state не обновляется при вызове setState React js

Tags: reactjs

У меня в юзЭфекте считается значение некоторых состояний, но почему-то не эти состояния не обновляются. Если вывести в консоль, то заметно, что только состояние остается неизменным.

```
setGroupedSout(groupByData(data.filter(item => item.soutWorkspaceCount !== 0)));
  setGroupedPk(groupByData(data.filter(item => item.pkWorkspaceCount !== 0)));
  console.log(groupByData(data.filter(item => item.soutWorkspaceCount !== 0)));
  console.log(groupByData(data.filter(item => item.pkWorkspaceCount !== 0)));
  console.log(groupedSout);
  console.log(groupedPk);
```

Вот что выводит консоль:
[image: Вывод консоли]

Comment: При таком выводе изменений не увидеть, т.к. собственно изменение стейта действие асинхронное и оно произойдет только "потом", т.е. после вывода `console.log()`.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что я неправильно выводил данные при рендере, поэтому они и не отображались. А то, что в консоли не выводится, это нормально, так и должно быть, это дефолтное поведение реакта, связанное с перерендерингом.